# Ansible: is there a way to load facts from a file on a target machine?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

With Ansible I'd like to store key-value pairs in a file on a on a target machine.

It would be created/changed by separate Ansible roles, possibly with actions like add/remove. I can already use [ansible-xml](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml) module for that purpose (however if the following was possible using different format, I don't mind).

Is there any "Ansibly" way to fetch the contents of the remote XML (or another format) file and populate the values into the facts (variables)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sure what you mean by *"remote file on the target machine"*, but take a look at [Local facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d).

You can store a static file at `/etc/ansible/facts.d/` on the target machine with some facts.
You can also write an executable script and put it there – it can do any stuff you want and then should print facts to stdout as JSON.

Comment: @techraf if you store static files in there – they can be in INI.

Comment: @techraf ah, sorry - missed that. You can play with `to_json`/`from_json` filters to move on with JSON.

Comment: I think I'll settle for this module fork: [ghetto_json](https://github.com/sangoma/ansible-ghetto-json).

Answer (score 3):

If the [Local facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) mechanism doesn't allow for enough flexibility, you can do this the manual way by using the built-in modules copy and slurp.

Storing facts can be done with the `copy` module using the `content` parameter. To load them, use the `slurp` module. Note that slurp encodes the file contents in Base64 encoding to prevent the Jinja2 parser from parsing the contents. But since that's exactly what you want, you can decode the contents with the `b64decode` filter.

**Example:**

```
- name: Set facts
  set_fact:
    data:
      testing: test string
      does_it_work: yes it does!

- name: Store facts
  copy:
    dest: /tmp/any_path_you_want
    content: "{{ data }}"

- name: Read facts
  slurp:
    src: /tmp/any_path_you_want
  register: slurp_output

- name: Load facts
  set_fact:
    data2: "{{ slurp_output['content'] | b64decode }}"

- name: Display facts
  debug:
    var: data2
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround - I was expecting something along the lines of `lookup('file-remote')`